# Lowering power circuit at data-center, please help clarify what PDU I need

Tags: networking, power-distribution-unit

I have the following question:

We have a rack at a datacenter with a 208V/60 amp circuit coming into a 208V/60 AMP PDU and I was wondering if we lower the circuit to let say 208V/30 amp or 120/30 amp do I need to change the PDU to a 208V/30 or 120/30 as to match the amperage on the circuit?

I guess my question is if the PDU has to always match the amperage and volts of the circuit?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Voltage has to match, amperage has to be less than or equal (but with some margin to spare).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to match no, all you're doing is potentially moving which part will trip out first.